# override a method for an instance of a class?

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible to reflectively override a method for a given instance of a class?

Precondition: Game has an override-able method `act()`.

```
public class Foo {

  public Method[] getMethods() {
    Class s = Game.class;
    return s.getMethods();
  }

  public void override()
  {
    Method[] arr = getMethods()
    for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
      if (arr[i].toGenericString().contains("act()")
      {
        // code to override method (it can just disable to method for all i care)
      }
    }  
  }                  
}
```

Comment: It is possible to do something like this using bytecode engineering and proxies, unless you really need this kind of black magic, just use composition and delegation.

Comment: Why is it not enough to use a method local anonymous inner class? Subclassing the actual class.

Comment: would it be easier to dynamically create a subclass from the given an instance, override the act method in that class, and dispose the previous instance?

Comment: never done this before but this question seems quite useful... looking forward for its answer.. +1 from my side...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If Game is an interface or implements an interface with the method `act()` you can use [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) for that. If the interface is small, the most elegant way would probably be to create a class implementing it employing the [Decorator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: Code examples ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to dynamically override methods of a class using pure Java. [The third-party library cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib/wiki) can create dynamic subclasses. You may want to check that out.

If you can code against interface, then you may use [Java dynamic proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) to create a proxy object which overrides the behavior, like the example below. Suppose `Game` was implementing an interface `IGame`.

```
class GameInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler
{
    private Game game;
    public GameInvocationHandler(Game game)
    {
        this.game = game;
    }
    Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
    {
        if (method.toGenericString().contains("act()")
        {
            //do nothing;
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return method.invoke(game, args);
        }
    }
}

Class proxyClass = Proxy.getProxyClass(Foo.class.getClassLoader(), IGame.class);
IGame f = (IGame) proxyClass.getConstructor(InvocationHandler.class).newInstance(new Object[] {  });
```